# Prism gobackasync from nested navigationpage

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Using xamarin forms prism:

My intention is to have the user enter a pw when trying to navigate back from "View3" and allow the navigation only if pw is correct.

I have the following stack: 
MasterDetail/Navigation1/View1/View2/Navigation2/View3

When i try to navigate from view2 to navigation2, I use modal navigation. So I dont have 2 navbars..

Navigation2 has a custom "exit" button. When pressed, I want to navigate back to View2 so my stack will be:
MasterDetail/Navigation/View1/View2

But when I try the following code, nothing happens:

```
 _navigationService.GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: false);
 _navigationService.GoBackAsync(useModalNavigation: true);
 _navigationService.GoBackToRootAsync();
```

And when I use `_navigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterDetail/Navigation/View1/View2", useModalNavigation:true);` it works but then it re-initialized the views, which i want to avoid.

What could be causing this? Am I doing something wrong?
thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [PR](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/pull/1427), you can now use this in Prism 7.1 and prior:

```
_navigationService.NavigateAsync("../../");
```

to pop the last 2 pages from the Navigation Stack.

Also you shouldn't have 2 navigation pages in the same stack, i can cause problems with your navigation, i sugest that you turn your View3 into a Modal Page and add a back verification for Android BackPress:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (((MyView3ViewModelPage)BindingContext).ExitCommand != null)
    {
        ((MyView3ViewModelPage)BindingContext).ExitCommand.Execute();
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

And create your own Back Button, since it's a Form and you won't navigate elsewhere from that, you have total control on how you present that page

Comment: i was going to say "omg how did i miss that" but this doesnt seem to work. nothing is happening :/

Comment: @RoyHarel i just tried on my side it poped 2 pages :/ did you used NavigateAsync or GoBackAsync?

Comment: i used NavigateAsync. 
to clarify, when i get current navigationuripath i get: 
"/MasterDetail/NavigationPage1/View1/View2/NavigationPage2?useModalNavigation=true/View3"

Comment: @RoyHarel give me a minute to recreate on my side with a modal page

Comment: i appreciate it! another clue: the result of navigateasyn is an exception "Index was out of range. " on this line: 
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/a4c131ab271fcab26c3ed9c5e3eb3316ec02a4ce/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Forms/Navigation/PageNavigationService.cs#L415
.. seems like it cant get past the second navigationpage...

Comment: @RoyHarel One question, why are you adding an extra NavigationPage into your stack?

Comment: in the app "view3" is a form a patient need to fill in. so when the patient gets the form i dont want him to be able to go back in any way only by using a pw which the "secretary" knows. so i was trying to override the software back of navigation page but apparently thats not possible, therefore i opted to create a new navigationpage so there is no software back, then i added a custom "exit" button which triggers a prompt to enter a pw before allowing to go back to the previous screen before "view3"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209376/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-roy-harel).

Comment: thanks for the help ricardo it let me down the right path!